# Expected value for alternating sum

Tags: probability, summation, expected-value

Pick any random number between 0 and 1 non-inclusive. The next number you pick, you will subtract from your first number. This goes on alternating back and forth between adding to the total and subtracting from the total. What is the expected value of numbers you must pick before the total is greater than 1. Is it infinity? Is it convergent? Not sure where to start. Thanks!

Comment: You might get some mileage out of treating the steps in pairs; that is, examine the embedded Markov chain where you look at the system at the start (some value between $0$ and $1$), then after two steps, after four steps, after six steps, etc.  What do you observe about the increments? ¶ It might help if you say something about the course of study you're engaged in.  For instance, are you learning about random walks?  Do you know what recurrent null and recurrent non-null are?  And so forth.

Comment: I'm just starting to dip my toes into probability, expected values, markov chains, etc. I haven't had a ton of experience and i'm currently not in a course, but I ant to learn more because of problems like these.

Comment: You might be reaching a bit too far ahead, in that case.  Are you working out of a text?  Where did you see this problem?

Comment: I just thought of this problem yesterday when I saw a similar problem online where you only add the numbers. I'm comfortable up to multi-variable calculus and differential equations level for math, which is why I attempted solving this problem using integration to find probabilities at various steps and trying to find a pattern,  but I have yet to directly take a probability or statics class.